# Odoo 9.0 domain, three models and two many2one fields

Tags: xml, python-2.7, model, odoo, odoo-9

I'm trying to filter a list of 'types' according to their 'class' for a specific 'scenario' but it either results with an empty field or a DataError, depending on the filter I use.

```
domain=[('aclass.name', '=', 'aclass_id.name')]
```

= an empty selection field,

```
domain=[('aclass.id', '=', 'aclass_id.id')]
```

=

```
...
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "aclass_id.id"
LINE 1: ...ass".id FROM "test_aclass" WHERE "test_aclass".id = 'aclass_id...
                                                         ^
```

Here is my model.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api


class Aclass (models.Model):
    _name = 'test.aclass'

    name = fields.Char()
    description = fields.Text()


class Atype (models.Model):
    _name = 'test.atype'

    name = fields.Char()
    description = fields.Text()
    aclass = fields.Many2one('test.aclass')

class Ascenario(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.ascenario'

    name = fields.Char()
    description = fields.Text()
    aclass_id = fields.Many2one('test.aclass')
    atype_id = fields.Many2one('test.atype', domain=[('aclass.id','=','aclass_id.id')])
```

And the form view :

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="ascenario_form_view">
        <field name="name">ascenario.form</field>
        <field name="model">test.ascenario</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Scenario">
                <sheet>
                <group string="Scenario">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="description"/>
                    <field name="aclass_id"/>
                    <field name="atype_id"/>
                </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

The atype_id field in the ascenario_form_view correctly displays the Atype list when there is no domain...

What am I missing?  Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better answer better the first with to solution:

for the dynamic domain like when you select a country you will show the states of that country only :

```
  class Ascenario(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.ascenario'
    name = fields.Char()
    description = fields.Text()
    aclass_id = fields.Many2one('test.aclass')
    atype_id = fields.Many2one('test.atype')
    @api.onchange('aclass_id')
    def daynamic_domain(self):
      return {'domain': {'atype_id': [('aclass','=',int(self.aclass_id.id))]}}
```

but :
If you want the reserve like the example when you select a state the country will be selected automaticly :

```
class Ascenario(models.Model):
  _name = 'test.ascenario'
  name = fields.Char()
  description = fields.Text()
  aclass_id = fields.Many2one(related='atype_id.aclass',readonly=True)
  atype_id = fields.Many2one('test.atype',)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this,

```
 atype_id = fields.Many2one('test.atype', domain=[('aclass','=',aclass_id)])
```

No need to specify field name in quote while you write that field in domain as value, and no need to specify ID over there.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, this option still results in an empty (atype_id) selection field in the view form. Something is missing.

Comment: Is there any data present in `test.aclass` ?

Comment: of course ;) - as I mentioned, "The atype_id field in the ascenario_form_view correctly displays the Atype list when there is no domain..." // but atype_id isnt filtered according to aclass_id